# How do I update data using Linq-to-sql?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I need to update a datatable using LINQToSql.
Option Strict is ON.

Datatable name is Customer with fields customerID, customerName, SalesID.
I need to update rows with SalesID = -1.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be one which takes advantages of LinqToSql

```
Dim Customer = (From cust in db.Customers Where cust.SalesID = -1).GetEnumerator
While Customer.MoveNext
    Customer.Current.SomeField = NewValue
End While
db.SubmitChanges()
```

where db is a fully qualified DataContext object.

Update (with a dataset):

```
    Dim cmdEditCustomer as String = "UPDATE Customers SET Myvalue = @Myvalue WHERE SalesID = -1"

Dim CN as New SqlConnection(ConnString)
DACustomers.UpdateCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdEditCustomer)
DACustomers.UpdateCommand.Connection = CN
Dim param as New SqlParameter
param.ParameterName = "@Myvalue"
param.sqldbtype = Sqldbtype.String ( or whatever it is)
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
param.Size = 15
Param.Value = "Whatever"
DaCustomers.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(param)
```

or

```
DACustomers.UpdateCommand(New System.Data.SqlClient.qlParameter(paramName,paramType,paramSize, _
paramDirection,ParamNullable,paramPrecision,paramScale,columnName,rowVersion,paramValue)
```

Comment: thanks Andris- it was my mistake to mention Linq-to-sql explicitly for updating a datatable. we still dont have put in the concept of DataContext i our apps. Without that, i hope, the above mentioned example by u, wouldnt be possible, isnt it? Isnt there a way using Linq-to-dataset ? Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @CocaCola: I edited a code with a dataset added,hope this helps